# Ansible syntax to run task based on host condition

Tags: ansible

I'm wondering if is it possible to have this kind of syntax to run a playbook based on host requirement :

- include: tomcat8_for_assc_team.yml
  when:
  hostgroup: assc
- include: tomcat8_for_oab_team.yml
  when:
  hostgroup: oab

In my Inventories files :

[assc]
vm1
vm2 
etc

[oab]
vm4
vm5
etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the magic variable group_names. it is described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables . They say: group_names is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in.

So in your case the following two tasks will do the job.

```
- name: "run the playbook for assc"
  include: "tomcat8_for_assc_team.yml"
  when: "'assc' in group_names"
- name: "run the playbook for oab"
  include: "tomcat8_for_oab_team.yml"
  when: "'oab' in group_names"
```

The first included playbook only runs if assc is in the gouplist of the current host. The second one is the same for goup oab.